# A problem occurred configuring project ':DragRecylerView'

Tags: android, build.gradle

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':DragRecylerView'.
```

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':DragRecylerView:classpath'.
> Could not find com.novoda:bintray-release:0.7.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/novoda/bintray-release/0.7.0/bintray-release-0.7.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/novoda/bintray-release/0.7.0/bintray-release-0.7.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :DragRecylerView

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

with build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.7.0'
    }
}

def version = "1.0.5"

publish {
    userOrg = 'shinhyo'
    groupId = 'com.wonshinhyo'
    artifactId = 'dragrecyclerview'
    publishVersion = version
    website = 'https://github.com/AleBarreto/DragRecyclerView'
    issueTracker = "${website}/issues"
    repository = "${website}.git"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.wonshinhyo.dragrecyclerview'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:' + rootProject.ext.supportVersion
}
```

D:\HeavenChat\DragRecylerView\build.gradle

Comment: hello, please provide the code of the build.gradle file, which is located at <your-project-name>/DragRecylerView/build.gradle

Comment: Now is edited the post

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

I'm using the latest version of dependency because `0.7.0` is not available to download from repositories (but you can find this version [here](https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release/releases)).

**Pay attention**: `bintray-release` is officially no longer under maintenance since `10.02.2022`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9.2'
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok i Will use that and i try thanks

Comment: @PusakaOfJavaSheor_ray, can you share your progress?

Comment: I Will update the progress but now any error on my API file on cake php